# Check if a Key is Down with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, keyboard-events

I am playing around with some graphics, and I have implemented simple camera movement with the arrow keys. My first approach was to override `keyPressEvent` to do something like this:

```
switch(key)
{
   case up: MoveCameraForward(step); break;
   case left: MoveCameraLeft(step); break;
   ...
}
```

This doesn't work as I wish it would. When I press and hold, for example, the forward key, the camera moves forward "step" units, then halts for a while and then continues moving. I am guessing that this is how the event is generated, in order to avoid multiple events in case of a little bit long keypress.

So, I need to poll the keyboard in my `Paint()` routine. I haven't found how to do it with Qt. I thought of having a `map<Key, bool>` which would be updated in `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` and poll that map in `Paint()`. Any better ideas? Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, I need to poll the keyboard in my Paint() routine. I haven't found
>   how to do it with Qt. I thought of having a map which would
>   be updated in keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent and poll that map in
>   Paint().

Your second method is what I would have done, except that I would use a continuous, periodic QTimer event to poll the keyboard-pressed map and call QWidget::Update() function when necessary to invalidate the display widget instead. Performing non-painting operations inside Paint() is strongly discouraged for many reasons but I do not know how to explain that well.

Comment: This is especially encouraged since the keyboard repeat rate can be setup by the user. This is the only way to guarantee it is independent from your internal tick rate.

Comment: There's a thread, and an example about this in the qt forums: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/135346/

Comment: I know I am answering 12 years later , but unfortunately QT still has no way we can easily check the state of some arbitrary key.


A warning: This approach might not work properly on Windows OS or even OSX when a window is being moved or resized and a key is released, that event will get lost. This can make it appear a key is held down indefinitely, leading to various unwanted bugs.


I've raised it on the forums: https://forum.qt.io/topic/145591/detecting-if-a-key-is-being-pressed

Comment: Was able to get a working solution with no found bugs yet, from discussion in my link provided above. Will leave another answer to extend this one

Answer (score 17):

This doesn't solve the general problem of detecting which keys are pressed, but if you are only looking for keyboard modifiers (shift, ctrl, alt, etc.), you can retrieve that through the static [`QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers) and [`QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#queryKeyboardModifiers) methods.

Comment: Qt::KeyboardModifiers QApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers() wokred for me using QT 4.8.7

Answer (score 3):

There is no Qt API for checking whether a key is pressed or not.
You may have to write separate code for different platforms and add a bit of `#ifdef` logic.

On Windows you can use `GetKeyState()` and `GetKeyboardState()`, both declared in `windows.h`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not straight forward when using Qt, but the Gluon team has been working on exactly that problem (along with a bunch of others). GluonInput solves the issue, and is available as part of Gluon: http://gluon.gamingfreedom.org/ It is also a nice, Qt-like API, so while it's an extra dependency, it should be possible for you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by auto repeation of keys:

> When I press and hold, for example, the forward key, the camera moves
> forward "step" units, then halts for a while and then continues
> moving.

In QT5 you can detect key held down by function `isAutoRepeat()` of `QKeyEvent` object. If the key is held down then `isAutoRepeat()` will return `true`.
for example:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        qDebug() << "[MainWindow::keyPressEvent()] " << event->key() << "; " << event->isAutoRepeat();
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->isAutoRepeat())
    {
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "[MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent()] " << event->key() << "; " << event->isAutoRepeat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@ksming's answer is good, but not complete and has a possible edge case that is not handled. It is possible on Windows and OSX that key events will not be received as a window is dragged, resized or loses focus. This can mean your map can get into an inconsistent state.

The best way to handle this is to reset the map whenever one of these events is detected, using `QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress`

That is,

1. When a key is pressed, note this in your map
2. When a key is released, remove it from your map
3. When the window is dragged clear your map - which allows you to remain in a consistent state, since you can't possibly know the state during that time.

The downside is you cannot handle events as the window is dragged or resized, but I think in the majority of use cases this should be fine. Just let the user handle these when they are done with their handling of the window. The alternative is handling keys in a platform dependant manner.

A word of warning - on OSX it appears you must listen to `NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress` from the application level itself. That is, a widget will not receive this event like it will on Windows.

```cpp
class KeyPressFilter : public QObject {
public:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* aObject, QEvent* aEvent) final {
        if (aEvent->type() == QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonPress) {
            // Handle your event here ...
            // Optionally return
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter(aObject, aEvent);
    }
};

{
    QApplication myApplication{...};
    
    KeyPressFilter myKeyFilter;
    myApplication.installEventFilter(&myKeyFilter);

    myApplication.exec();
}
```

Something like this should work

You might also want to handle `QEvent::WindowDeactivate` for exactly the same reason (if the focus is changed as keys are being handled).

A link to a discussion on this issue can be found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/145591/detecting-if-a-key-is-being-pressed) (accurate as of QT 6.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Use QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers() and QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers() for keyboard modifiers in Qt5