# ArrowKey Control More Fluid

Tags: c++, qt, events, arrow-keys

I am using

```
         event->key()== Qt::Key_Down
```

to control and object using arrow keys in Qt.
I have the same for all the arrow keys(right, left, up and down) but what happens is its very rigid. Like to go right and down you have to press the right arrow key then release it and press the down arrow key. Whereas I want the user to be able to pres both and for it to reposition that way. I tried this but to no avail.

```
     else if(event->key()== Qt::Key_Down && event->key()== Qt::Key_Right ){ 

   setPos(x()+10,y()+10);

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

As with most event handlers, Qt only tells you when a key is pressed, and puts all the keypresses into a queue. So your code with the `&&` will never be called, as the keypresses if Qt::Key_Down and Qt::Key_Right will be processed one after the other.

What you want is a function which checks whether the key is being held, i.e. if left is held down then go left, and if down is held down go down, and if both are held down then go down-left.

Qt has no function for this. Others have recommended os-specific solutions e.g. using `windows.h` and `#ifdefs`.

Check out this question:
[Check if a Key is Down with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394660/check-if-a-key-is-down-with-qt)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pressed key to the set of pressed keys and remove from this set when the key is released. So add the pressed key to a `QSet` which is a class member :

```
QSet<int> pressedKeys;
```

Your event filter would be like :

```
bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if(event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress) {

        pressedKeys += ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key();

        f( pressedKeys.contains(Qt::Key_Down) && pressedKeys.contains(Key_Right) )
        {
            setPos(x()+10,y()+10);
        }

    }
    else if(event->type()==QEvent::KeyRelease)
    {

        pressedKeys -= ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key();
    }


    return false;
}
```